# How to send image to another activity in android?

Tags: android

I have a set of array which i am displaying in imageview during a specified interval of time.What i want when i click image i want to show that image in another activity.How can i do that

code:-

```
int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.amazon, R.drawable.app_me,
        R.drawable.borabora, R.drawable.dubai};
public void showImage(){
    m_oHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable oRunnable = new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            img.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
            i++;
            if (i > imageArray.length - 1) {
                i = 0;
            }
            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //  Didn't know where to go
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                    intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", imageArray);
                }
            });
            m_oHandler.postDelayed(this, 6000);

        }
    };
    m_oHandler.postDelayed(oRunnable, 6000);
}
```

Comment: You can pass the position of the arraylist and make the arraylist static so you can use it globally.

Comment: How.......................................

Comment: Define all images in res/values/array.xml file and pass only position to next activity. Access array in next activity and fetch image :)

Comment: Why are you using `ImageView`? You can also use `ImageView` inside `ViewPager` for displaying series of images

Answer (score 1):

Do Not Pass Bitmap object.
Instead pass id of drawable resources.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
intent.putExtra("image_res_ids", CollectonUtils.join("/", imageArray);
```

And in `Second` Activity,

```
getIntent().getExtra("image_res_ids");
```

to get image resource id array.

Answer (score 1):

> want when i click image i want to show that image in another activity.

Use `img` `setTag()` method for saving current drawable id and get it back on click of view using `getTag()`

**1.** set drawable id using setTag:

```
....
img.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
img.setTag(imageArray[i]);
....
```

**2.** Get id from `v` inside onClick method:

```
int click_drawable_id=Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
intent.putExtra("clicked_img_draw_id", click_drawable_id);
```

Now instead of passing  `imageArray`  Array, just use `clicked_img_draw_id` to  get drawable id and pass it to `setImageResource` to show clicked image in another Activity.

Comment: and How to get extra

Comment: @Raghav: Use `int draw_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("clicked_img_draw_id", -1); ` in onCreate of Second Activity

Answer (score 0):

Your images are drawable resources, which are nothing more that an int. So you can definitely pass them as extras in an Intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the array as an extra and then  fetch it with `getIntent().getIntArrayExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE)`

For more details have a look at [Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

you save the index/resource id using setTag  i.e do img.setTag(index) as follows.
And fowarding it you can remove the index/resource id from tag and pass as intent extra

```
 @Override
        public void run() {
            img.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
            img.setTag(i)
            i++;
            //your code
            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //  Didn't know where to go
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                    intent.putExtra("IMAGE_RESOURCE", img.getTag());
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

just try to send position of your selected image

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
```

get intent

```
Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
```

Check this for more http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to pass single image to next activity, than in your case, only pass image index like

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                    intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", imageArray[i]);

and on next activity get it. like 
int image_id= getIntent().getIntExtra("BitmapImage",0);

this image_id is your selected image resouce id  and you can set this as setImageresouce to image view.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
previewView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPostIssue);
```

> First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AddNewIssue.this, PostNewIssue.class);
        intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
```

> Second Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
            if (byteArray != null) {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPostIssue);

                image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        }
```

Try this out, it will definitely work.. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTag()`. Check this out

BitmapCache.java

```
public class BitmapCache {

    private static SparseArray<Bitmap> _bitmapCache = new SparseArray<>();

    public static void fillBitmapCache(@NonNull Resources resources) {
        if (null == _bitmapCache)
            _bitmapCache = new SparseArray<>();

        if (_bitmapCache.indexOfKey(R.drawable.amazon) < 0)
            _bitmapCache.append(R.drawable.amazon, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.amazon));

        if (_bitmapCache.indexOfKey(R.drawable.app_me) < 0)
            _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.app_me, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.app_me));

        if (_bitmapCache.indexOfKey(R.drawable.borabora) < 0)
            _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.borabora, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.borabora));

        if (_bitmapCache.indexOfKey(R.drawable.dubai) < 0)
            _bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.dubai, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.dubai));
    }

    public static Bitmap getAt(int position) {
        return get(keyAt(position));
    }

    public static int keyAt(int position) {
        return _bitmapCache.keyAt(position);
    }

    public static Bitmap get(@DrawableRes int resId) {
        return _bitmapCache.get(resId);
    }

    public static boolean has(@DrawableRes int resId) {
        return _bitmapCache.indexOfKey(resId) < 0;
    }

    public static void append(@DrawableRes int resId, @NonNull Resources resources) {
        _bitmapCache.append(resId, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resId));
    }

    public static void put(@DrawableRes int resId, @NonNull Resources resources) {
        _bitmapCache.put(resId, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resId));
    }

    public static int size() {
        return _bitmapCache.size();
    }
}
```

Activity First

```
 private void showImage() {
        BitmapCache.fillBitmapCache(getResources());

        m_oHandler = new Handler();
        Runnable oRunnable = new Runnable() {
            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                img.setImageBitmap(BitmapCache.getAt(i));
                img.setTag(BitmapCache.keyAt(i));
                i++;
                if (i >= BitmapCache.size()) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (null != v.getTag()) {
                            int resId = (int) v.getTag();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                            intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", resId);
                        }
                    }
                });
                m_oHandler.postDelayed(this, 6000);

            }
        };
        m_oHandler.postDelayed(oRunnable, 6000);
    }
```

Second Activity

```
private void displayImageOnSecond() {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int resId = bundle.getInt("BitmapImage", 0);

        if (resId > 0) {
            secondImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapCache.get(resId));
        }
    }
```

Also I recommend to use `ViewPager` and customize it for auto rotate rather than the one you using currently. `Runnable` may cause memory leaks if `Activity` has been destroyed